# Center a button in table

Tags: html, css, email, button

I built a button inside a table, but can't manage to centre it. Can you help? I think the CSS isn't correct, but can't get it running. Any help would be appreciated. Also, the button should show in an email, in case that makes a difference.

[image]

```css
.button a {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    
    
}
```

```html
<tr>
                                      <td class="plr-10" style="padding:0 60px;">
                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                          <tbody style=""><tr>
                                            <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tbody><tr style="">
                                                  <td class="text-16 tx-grey" valign="top" width="10" style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:26px;text-align:left;min-width:auto !important;color:#929292;">
                                                    <strong style="font-weight: bold;">
                                                      <br>1.</strong>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="img" width="10" style="font-size:0pt;line-height:0pt;text-align:left;"></td>
                                                    <td class="text-16" valign="top" style="color: rgb(37, 46, 93); font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 26px; text-align: left; min-width: auto !important;"><br>
Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text .</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </tbody></table>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                              
                                              
                                              
                                              
                  
                  <tbody><tr>
                  <td class="button a">
                      <table width="40%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody><tr>
                          <td class="button" style="padding-bottom:25px; text-align: center">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tbody><tr>
                               <td class="button" width="240" style="font-family:'Segoe UI', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:16px;min-width:auto !important;text-align:center;color:#ffffff;" bgcolor="#1b55f5" >
                                  <a href="" target="_blank" class="link-grey" style="color:#b5b5b5;text-decoration:none;"><span class="link-grey" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">Browse</span></a>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

Comment: You have a table nested in a table, and added the class 'button' to the single cell of the inner table.  Since the outer table has width=40%, it appears as it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an actual button:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <button class="button">hello</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should center the button itself:

```
.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. The button is still left aligned.

Comment: Hmmm, it works in the browser, but not in email clients.

Comment: Note that I also deleted the 40% table width in the HTML.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't make a difference. The problem is that flexbox doens't work in email clients.